# Getting full image URL of product in template

Tags: magento2, product, template, image

I'm trying to create a static block for showing dynamic products. This is code that is supposed to get every child category and print the image for each product in each category.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    ?><ol><?php
    foreach ($category->getChildrenCategories() as $child_category) {
        ?><li>
            <ul><?php
                foreach ($child_category->getProductCollection() as $product) {
                    ?><li><img src="<?php echo $product->getImage();?>"/><li><?php
                }
            ?></ul>
        </li><?php
    }
    ?></ol>
```

It is almost working except for the img srcs are only "/a/b/ab001.jpg" as an example and not the full path e.g. "/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/abc123def456/a/b/001.jpg" so the images cannot be found. What is the correct way of getting product images?

Comment: **Don't** try to use Object Manager directly on your template. We should create new block or re-use exist functions.

Answer (score 39):

If your block extends `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`, you can use:

```
$imageType = 'category_page_list'; // choose which image
$image = $block->getImage($product, $imageType);
```

Then either get the image URL with

```
$image->getImageUrl();
```

or if you want to output it as `<img>` element:

```
echo $image->toHtml();
```

---

If your block does not / cannot extend the abstract product block, you can create a `getImage()` method on your own:

```
public function getImage($product, $imageId)
{
    return $this->imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
        ->setImageId($imageId)
        ->create();
}
```

`$this->imageBuilder` has to be injected as `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder`

---

The `$imageType` or `$imageId` variables should be one of the image types defined in the theme, for example `category_page_list`.

See [`app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/732d445fe68b2c00a03dda546e3813dea04d441e/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml) for all image types in the Luma theme, for example.

In Magento 2 these image types are used instead of defining width and height directly in the template.

Comment: I am trying your code but i am getting this error `Uncaught Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFoundException: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg'`

Comment: @ND17 two questions: 1) are you using the block in the admin area? This code is intended for frontend only 2) do you have configured a placeholder image? If not and a product has no image, you'll always get errors

Comment: 1)I am use this code in my cron php 2) Yes i configured placeholder image and product have so many image

Comment: Cron is also a separate area from frontend. But are you really rendering a template in the cron or do you just need the image URL? The question is about **templates**. To render templates in the cron you probably need store emulation. But this would be a different question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this is for template and i want to send email using cron and want image url...And yeah its working in template

Comment: what's `$imageId` ?

Comment: @davideghz one of the image types defined in the theme, for example `category_page_list`. See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/732d445fe68b2c00a03dda546e3813dea04d441e/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml in Magento 2 you use these instead of defining width and height directly in the template

Comment: Any idea of why it would bring back the placeholder instead of the assigned image?

Comment: That's fine if you're using an image type that's defined in view.xml, however, you can't use the image builder at all if you've got a custom image type.

Comment: @Erfan why would a custom image type not be defined in view.xml?

Comment: I am having the same problem as @Laura. It always returns the placeholder image instead of the assigned image (the assigned image is perfectly visible in the product list or generic product details page otherwise).

Answer (score 9):

If you need to resize the product image and use the default Magento image cache system and you are not in the frontend area, you can use this workaround.

Use case :
It may be useful if you need image URLs resized on your custom API for an external application.

**Function code :**

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $productFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
 */
protected $helperFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
 */
protected $appEmulation;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
    $this->productFactory                   = $productFactory;
    $this->imageBuilder                     = $imageBuilder;
    $this->helperFactory                    = $helperFactory;
    $this->appEmulation                     = $appEmulation;
    $this->storeManager                     = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * Retrieve product image
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @param string $imageId
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image
 */
public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
{
    $image = $this->helperFactory->create()->init($product, $imageId)
        ->constrainOnly(true)
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->keepTransparency(true)
        ->keepFrame(false)
        ->resize(200, 300);

    return $image;
}

public function customFunction()
{
    // some stuff here

    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('sku', 'productSKU');
    $imageUrl = $this->getImage($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();

    echo $imageUrl;

    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

    // some stuff here
}
```

**The output example :**

```
http://{domain}/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/200x300/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/s/r/{imageName}.jpg
```

**Comments :**

The third parameter of the function *startEnvironmentEmulation* is used to force the use of frontend area if you are already on the same storeId. (usefull for API area)

This workaround avoid you to have this kind of errors :

```
http://XXXX.com/pub/static/webapi_rest/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg

Uncaught Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFoundException: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeh‌​older/.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the environment emulation, just what I needed.

Comment: The environment emulation saved my day. Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Try it

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Comment: This one is good because it will automatically give the secure / insecure URL according to the current request

Answer (score 4):

Try This code..

```
$ProductImageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getImage();
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Answers that only contain one line of code are often not very helpful. In this case it's relatively clear how this line is supposed to be used, but using `getUrl()` is not the right way even if it may work accidentally. It takes a `$route` parameter in the form "module/controller/action". "pub/media/catalog" looks like a route, but is not.

Comment: Doesn't use the object manager, good answer. Even if only one line.

Comment: @LM_Fielding Not every answer that doesn't use the object manager is automatically good.

Comment: Try this code and post your comment

Answer (score 3):

You can use ObjectManager or Block.

Objectmanager :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Block :

```
protected $_storeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
  ...
)
{
  ...
  $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
  ...
}

...

public function getStoreInterface($imgUrl){
   $store = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore();
   $storeMedia = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $imgUrl;
   return $storeMedia;
}
...
```

Call the function :

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getStoreInterface($imgUrl) ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product::getImageUrl()` could help.
I don't understand why Magento developers didn't implement it in `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image` class since the `getUrl` method in image helper does not return what one could expect...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
$prdId = 35;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$hotPrd = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prdId);
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
echo $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $hotPrd->getThumbnail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<img class="test-image" alt="image" src="<?php echo $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog/product', ['_secure' => $block->getRequest()->isSecure()]).$product->getImage();?>" />
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is adding an src of "https://www.domain.com/pub/media/catalog//a/b/ab001.jpg" which also cannot be found

Comment: Missing the product directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your module:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    //... create collection code goes here...

    $result = [ ];

    foreach ( $collection as $product ) {
        $result[] = [
            'id'        => $product->getId(),
            '_sku'      => $product->getSku(),
            'permalink' => $product->getProductUrl($product),
            'title'     => $product->getName(),
            'raw_price' => $product->getPrice(),
            'image_url' => $this->getUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product'.$product->getImage()
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Then in your block you'll get this result:

```
print_r($block->getProducts());
```

Well, it's not perfect, but it works for me.

Take a look at result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$childcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

foreach($childcategories as $child)
    {
echo '<li class="sub-cat">';
        $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($child->getId()); 
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl(); ?>">
        <div class="sub-title">
            <h3><?php echo $cat->getName();?></h3>
        </div> 
    <?php
        if ($_imgUrl = $cat->getImageUrl())
        {
            $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $block->escapeHtml($cat->getName()) . '" title="' . $block->escapeHtml($cat->getName()) . '" class="image" /></div>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($cat, $_imgHtml, 'image');
            /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
        }  

    ?>      
    <?php echo '</a></li>'; }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class inject dependency StoreManagerInterface like:

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterfac $storeManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    }
```

after in your method, for obtain thumbail for example

```
public function getProductThumbnail(){

        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another working method:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager */
$url = $urlManager->getDirectUrl('pub/media/catalog/product' . $product->getImage());
```

Or respecting secure / insecure URL based on current request:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
$url = $urlManager->getDirectUrl(
    'pub/media/catalog/product' . $product->getImage(),
    ['_secure' => $request->isSecure()]
);
```

I'll leave the object instantiation to your own imagination.

Answer (score 0):

We can get Base Image url in phtml file

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
<?php $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>
```