# magento 2 rest api search results display with filter options

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, search, api-filter

I am new to magento 2. I have to develop **Rest api** search service list with **categories filter** option like web application. Is that possible kindly help me anyone

[image]

Comment: Please guide me anyone

Answer (score 2):

You can based on the native Magento 2 search API : `\Magento\Framework\Search\Search::search`

The API definition : `vendor/magento/module-search/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<route url="/V1/search" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface" method="search"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Then build your request such as :

```
http://{domainName}/index.php/rest/V1/search/?searchCriteria[requestName]=configurator_quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=searchTermValueExample&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_ids&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2
```

You can specify price aggregation algorithm and price filters :

```
http://192.168.56.4/index.php/rest/V1/search/?searchCriteria[requestName]=configurator_quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]=category_ids&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]=2&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][2][field]=price.from&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][2][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][3][field]=price.to&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][3][value]=10000&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][4][field]=price_dynamic_algorithm&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][4][value]=auto
```

The definition of the search request can be found here : `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml`

```
<request query="quick_search_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
    <dimensions>
        <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
    </dimensions>
    <queries>
        <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="quick_search_container" boost="1">
            <queryReference clause="should" ref="search" />
            <queryReference clause="must" ref="category"/>
            <queryReference clause="must" ref="price"/>
            <queryReference clause="must" ref="visibility"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="matchQuery" value="$search_term$" name="search">
            <match field="sku"/>
            <match field="*"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="category">
            <filterReference clause="must" ref="category_filter"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="price">
            <filterReference clause="must" ref="price_filter"/>
        </query>
        <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="visibility">
            <filterReference clause="must" ref="visibility_filter"/>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <filters>
        <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="category_filter" field="category_ids" value="$category_ids$"/>
        <filter xsi:type="rangeFilter" name="price_filter" field="price" from="$price.from$" to="$price.to$"/>
        <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="visibility_filter" field="visibility" value="$visibility$"/>
    </filters>
    <aggregations>
        <bucket name="price_bucket" field="price" xsi:type="dynamicBucket" method="$price_dynamic_algorithm$">
            <metrics>
                <metric type="count"/>
            </metrics>
        </bucket>
        <bucket name="category_bucket" field="category_ids" xsi:type="termBucket">
            <metrics>
                <metric type="count"/>
            </metrics>
        </bucket>
    </aggregations>
    <from>0</from>
    <size>10000</size>
</request>
```

You can create your own search_request based on this file.

Response example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <items>
    <item>
      <id>34</id>
      <custom_attributes>
        <item>
          <attribute_code>_score</attribute_code>
          <value>1.0875742</value>
        </item>
      </custom_attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>29</id>
      <custom_attributes>
        <item>
          <attribute_code>_score</attribute_code>
          <value>1.049452</value>
        </item>
      </custom_attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>44</id>
      <custom_attributes>
        <item>
          <attribute_code>_score</attribute_code>
          <value>1.049452</value>
        </item>
      </custom_attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>45</id>
      <custom_attributes>
        <item>
          <attribute_code>_score</attribute_code>
          <value>1.049452</value>
        </item>
      </custom_attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>13</id>
      <custom_attributes>
        <item>
          <attribute_code>_score</attribute_code>
          <value>1.0122644</value>
        </item>
      </custom_attributes>
    </item>
  </items>
  <aggregations>
    <buckets>
      <item>
        <name>price_bucket</name>
        <values>
          <item>
            <value>*_100</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>*_100</item>
              <item>1</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>100_200</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>100_200</item>
              <item>0</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>200_300</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>200_300</item>
              <item>0</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>300_400</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>300_400</item>
              <item>1</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>400_500</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>400_500</item>
              <item>1</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>500_*</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>500_*</item>
              <item>2</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
        </values>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>category_bucket</name>
        <values>
          <item>
            <value>2</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>2</item>
              <item>5</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>25</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>25</item>
              <item>4</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
          <item>
            <value>24</value>
            <metrics>
              <item>24</item>
              <item>1</item>
            </metrics>
          </item>
        </values>
      </item>
    </buckets>
    <bucket_names>
      <item>price_bucket</item>
      <item>category_bucket</item>
    </bucket_names>
  </aggregations>
  <search_criteria>
    <request_name>configurator_quick_search_container</request_name>
    <filter_groups>
      <item>
        <filters>
          <item>
            <field>search_term</field>
            <value></value>
            <condition_type>eq</condition_type>
          </item>
          <item>
            <field>category_ids</field>
            <value>2</value>
            <condition_type>eq</condition_type>
          </item>
          <item>
            <field>price.from</field>
            <value>1</value>
            <condition_type>eq</condition_type>
          </item>
          <item>
            <field>price.to</field>
            <value>10000</value>
            <condition_type>eq</condition_type>
          </item>
          <item>
            <field>price_dynamic_algorithm</field>
            <value>auto</value>
            <condition_type>eq</condition_type>
          </item>
        </filters>
      </item>
    </filter_groups>
  </search_criteria>
  <total_count>5</total_count>
</response>
```

Then create your own logic to retrieve product collection based on the productIds.

You can based on the Magento 2 native logic.

Overview:

1. Create the product collection
2. Create a temporary table with search product ids results
3. Join your product collection with the search results ids
4. Retrieve data

Comment: I recommend you to use this layer. In the future if you use another search engine such as ElasticSearch, your code will be compatible

Comment: If you need to return frontend image URL from your custom API, you can check my post : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/144654/46873

Comment: Thanks, rest/V1/products/attributes/center_diamond_size/options service working meanwhile rest/V1/products/attributes/price/options not working. has any possible way to get price options . please guide me franck

Comment: What do you mean by price option ? Is it related to configurable ? You API call is used to retrieve EAV attribute options.

Comment: The filters are created dynamically based on the response. Try to add price filters on your request.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Dear Franck, I want web service api like filter search of web application for mobile app. Is that possible to provide search web service. Please help me. am so much frustrated by that

Comment: Please read my post. You have enought information to build this API.

Comment: Hi Franck, I need one more help. I want to implement product custom option in onestep checkout page also. is that possible? kindly help me franck

Comment: It is not the main topic, create another post.

Comment: please see the page. I created new post "http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146451/how-to-display-product-custom-option-in-onestep-checkout-page-in-magento-2-1". please help me franck

Comment: @FranckGarnier You save a lot of time by given answer. Thanks.

Comment: @FranckGarnier have you created any module like above scenario?

Comment: I created my custom module yes. But it is specific for my customer