# Gel All Product images url using product id

Tags: magento-2.1, url, product-images

Most of magento products have more than one product image, i've read this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107467/getting-full-image-url-of-product-in-template) on how to retrieve product image url, but it seems it only retrieve one image, i want to to load the product images url only by using product id and when i copy the one of images url to browser window the image will show up , is there any chance to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to load a product by Its ID, for this, use below code in your block file : [Reference](https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-product-id-sku-magento-2.html)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class ProductImages extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }
}
```

Then use below in your phtml to display images.

```
$_productId = 1;
$product = $this->getProductById($_productId);
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach($images as $child){
    echo $child->getUrl()."<br>"; // Your Images URL
}
```

Comment: when i try to access the image url i got 404:page not found

Comment: Can you share your image url path here? just only after media folder.

Comment: .../catalog/product/w/s/wsh12-green_alt1.jpg

Comment: The path seems to be correct. It should display you image. Please make sure you have the image available for the product and also check your folder if the image exist at above path.

Comment: look up in pub/media/catalog/product folder there is no w folder

Comment: Can you make sure if the product is available in admin panel product edit section.